# Single table with internal relationship - Constraint fails when inserting deleting

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, constraints, relationship

I have a table "office" which has the following fields:

- id, int(10) unsigned auto_inc
- fk_office, int(10) unsigned, can be NULL
- address
- url
- email

An office may depend from another (for building the dependency tree) so I've built with phpMyAdmin a foreign key relationship to the same table that states:

> **office.fk_office relates to office.id - ON DELETE SET NULL, ON UPDATE CASCADE**

I think this means that when an office is deleted its fk_office should be set NULL, without deleting its children offices, and when an office is updated, its children offices should also do, am I wrong?

**Now my problem is when inserting**. I have other tables (phone, hour, etc) that list phone-fax numbers for each office and business hours. These tables have FKs pointing to the office table (id field)

Why I'm getting

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

when inserting a new record into office table?
Should I optimize/change this design?

Thanks

Comment: are you inserting an fk_office value into this office table? if it's something OTHER than null, you'll have to ensure the matching record exists in your db already. e.g. `insert (1)` when no `1` record exists will ive this error, whereas `insert (null)` would success, because you're allowing nulls in that fk field.

Comment: Please include the INSERT statements you are doing for the other tables.